# How can i open a case page or a contact page from an aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, case, lightning-apps, contact

I have an aura lightening component that i am rendering in the utility bar, which i am rendering in a lightning app.

If i have a salesforce case record id, or contact record id, is it possible to open the case page or the contact page of that id, from this aura component?

If yes, how can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

For that You have to use the Lightning Navigation which is use to navigate to a given pagereference.

Refer this documention [Lightning Navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)